# Q/KDB+: Percentile function excluding nulls

Tags: kdb, q-lang

What's the least verbose way to express [percentile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) (not to be confused with [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)) in Q, excluding nulls?

I have:

```
q)x:0N 1 2 0N 2 1 5
q)@[count[x]#0Nf;i;:;(1%count i)*1+rank x i:where not null x]
0n 0.2 0.6 0n 0.8 0.4 1
```

Problem with the `rank` above is that ties actually don't end up with the equal probability/percentile value.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't think this is the most optimal solution, but it should solve the issue:

```
{   
  X: x where not null x; 
  grouped: group asc X;
  firstRank: first each value grouped;
  quantiles: (key grouped)! firstRank%count X;
  quantiles x
}[0N 1 2 0N 2 1 5]
```

The code

1. Filters out nulls from input array
2. Sorts array in ascending order and groups it by every element. Which gives map of the next structure 1 2 5 ! (0 1; 2 3; 4)
3. Gets the first index by the key: 1 2 5 ! 0 2 4
4. Gets quantile function value based on (3)
5. Maps input array elements to corresponding quantile

Comment: thanks @Anton, I've played in the meantime as well. Your solution slightly differs from Wikipedia examples, but is nevertheless one of the two fastest. The other fastest solution has slightly lower memory footprint

Answer (score 0):

I've compared several approaches (including `prank4` from the other answer):

```
prank1:{
  n:asc x where not null x;
  (sums[count each group n]%count n) @ x
  }
prank2:{
  p:(1+(asc n) bin n)%count n:x i:where not null x;
  @[count[x]#0Nf;i;:;p]
  }
prank3:{@[((1+til[count i])%count i)@last each group asc i:x where not null x;x]}

prank4:{   
  X: x where not null x; 
  grouped: group asc X;
  firstRank: first each value grouped;
  quantiles: (key grouped)! firstRank%count X;
  quantiles x
  }
```

Check that output is consistent to [the nearest rank method of percentile calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile), except `prank4`:

```
prank1 0N 1 2 0N 2 1 5 / 0n 0.4 0.8 0n 0.8 0.4 1
```

Compare timings and memory footprint:

```
x:10000000?0N,til 500
\ts prank1 x  /  494 402661632
\ts prank2 x  / 3905 671088960
\ts prank3 x  /  552 536879392
\ts prank4 x  /  496 533741888
prank2[x]~prank1 x / 1b
prank1[x]~prank3 x / 1b
prank1[x]~prank4 x / 0b
```